# Phonegap error using only phonegap Not using Phonegap + native

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, mobile, phonegap-plugins

I Have asked this for many days ago I think this is now goes in queue so I am posting this again please tell me any one can help me

```
ERROR    the connection to the server was unsuccessful. (file ///android_asset/www/index.html) pure    phonegap app
```

Code follows :

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-mobile/jqm-docs.css">
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.loadingMessageTextVisible = true;
});
</script>
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery_mobile_old.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).on("click", ".show-page-loading-msg", function() {
        var $this = $( this ),
            theme = $this.jqmData("theme") || $.mobile.loadingMessageTheme,
            msgText = $this.jqmData("msgtext") || $.mobile.loadingMessage,
            textonly = !!$this.jqmData("textonly");
        $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(theme, msgText, textonly);
    })
    .on("click", ".hide-page-loading-msg", function() {
        $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div data-role="header"><h1>My App</h1></div>

<a href="http://xyz.php" style="text-decoration:none">
<button class="show-page-loading-msg">xyz</button>
</a> <a href="http://xyz.php" style="text-decoration:none">
<button class="show-page-loading-msg">xyz</button>
</a> <a href="http://xyz.php" style="text-decoration:none">
<button class="show-page-loading-msg">xyz</button>
</a> <a href="http://xyz.php" style="text-decoration:none">
<button class="show-page-loading-msg">xyz</button>
</a> <a href="http://xyz.php" style="text-decoration:none">
<button class="show-page-loading-msg">xyz</button>
</a> <a href="http://xyz.php" style="text-decoration:none">
<button class="show-page-loading-msg">xyz</button>
</a> <a href="http://xyz.php" style="text-decoration:none">
<button class="show-page-loading-msg">xyz</button>
</a> <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none">
<button class="show-page-loading-msg">Outstanding Analysis For Creditors</button>
</a>
```

But it is working perfectly in browser.

The problem is when I am trying to open this in phone it is giving error.I am using Dreamweaver CS6 and building it in https://build.phonegap.com/

Answer (score 0):

when using the build.phonegap.com, do you have access to the .java file which contains the activity to load the page. if yes, then check the path most likely, the url to the web page is not correct.

also is the name of the html file correct as shown in the error message.

did you look at the documentation in this [page](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/preparing-your-app#what_do_i_upload).. bear in mind that the file name is index.html and not index.htm or any other thing.

**Update:**
I have tried to put the code of phonegap.js into a seperate file but did not include the reference to phonegap.js, the application did not work. so it seems, it is important to include the reference to phonegap.js in the index.html file.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=3, maximum-scale=3, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=high-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css" />

      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>
      <script src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.loadingMessageTextVisible = true;
});
</script>
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery_mobile_old.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).on("click", ".show-page-loading-msg", function() {
        var $this = $( this ),
            theme = $this.jqmData("theme") || $.mobile.loadingMessageTheme,
            msgText = $this.jqmData("msgtext") || $.mobile.loadingMessage,
            textonly = !!$this.jqmData("textonly");
        $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(theme, msgText, textonly);
    })
    .on("click", ".hide-page-loading-msg", function() {
        $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div data-role="header"><h1>My App</h1></div>

<a href="http://xyz.php" style="text-decoration:none">
<button class="show-page-loading-msg">xyz</button>
</a> <a href="http://xyz.php" style="text-decoration:none">
<button class="show-page-loading-msg">xyz</button>
</a> <a href="http://xyz.php" style="text-decoration:none">
<button class="show-page-loading-msg">xyz</button>
</a> <a href="http://xyz.php" style="text-decoration:none">
<button class="show-page-loading-msg">xyz</button>
</a> <a href="http://xyz.php" style="text-decoration:none">
<button class="show-page-loading-msg">xyz</button>
</a> <a href="http://xyz.php" style="text-decoration:none">
<button class="show-page-loading-msg">xyz</button>
</a> <a href="http://xyz.php" style="text-decoration:none">
<button class="show-page-loading-msg">xyz</button>
</a> <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none">
<button class="show-page-loading-msg">Outstanding Analysis For Creditors</button>
</a>
```

Comment: This is my index.html page and I am not using any .java file.

Comment: i never used build.phonegap.com before. but out of curiosity i had taken a look at it. it seems the only problem when using the app is if the code that is uploaded either via zip file or using repository, is that if the folder structure is not correct.

Comment: folder structure is ok if put `<body>Hello</body>` in this page and remove all the js file then page is loading in the phone properly.

Comment: i should have realised this earlier but ur page is missing the reference to `<script src="phonegap.js"></script>` .. if you look at the link that i provided in my answer there is a section which states that you need to have the reference.. **[link](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/preparing-your-app#what_do_i_upload)**

Comment: this is the file `<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery_mobile_old.js"></script>`

Comment: may be when building the application it is searching for the line specifically which states phonegap.js .. if your js contains the code from phonegap.js then may be you should try removing it and making a reference in the index.html to include phonegap.js

Comment: please see above the update code in my answer, i have tried to build and deploy on my phone and it works.

Comment: here is the zip file i used to upload on the build.phonegap.com .. http://www.speedyshare.com/Ay4HW/www.zip .. check if you still face the same issue

Comment: This is uploaded in a paid uploader

Comment: No its not just click on the file name